planning frequency of moveit is too slow How can i make it plan faster?
I am tryin to get my robot to accept at least 10 new, but only slightly diffenrent joint states per sekond but currently when i try doing it in moveit it only does one every 0.9 sekonds how do i speed this up?
import socket
import json
import sys
import copy
import rospy
import moveit_commander
import moveit_msgs.msg
import geometry_msgs.msg
from math import pi
from std_msgs.msg import String
from moveit_commander.conversions import pose_to_list
import time
## END_SUB_TUTORIAL


def all_close(goal, actual, tolerance):
  """
  Convenience method for testing if a list of values are within a tolerance of their counterparts in another list
  @param: goal       A list of floats, a Pose or a PoseStamped
  @param: actual     A list of floats, a Pose or a PoseStamped
  @param: tolerance  A float
  @returns: bool
  """
  all_equal = True
  if type(goal) is list:
    for index in range(len(goal)):
      if abs(actual[index] - goal[index]) > tolerance:
        return False

  elif type(goal) is geometry_msgs.msg.PoseStamped:
    return all_close(goal.pose, actual.pose, tolerance)

  elif type(goal) is geometry_msgs.msg.Pose:
    return all_close(pose_to_list(goal), pose_to_list(actual), tolerance)

  return True

class MoveGroupPythonIntefaceTutorial(object):
  """MoveGroupPythonIntefaceTutorial"""
  def __init__(self):
    super(MoveGroupPythonIntefaceTutorial, self).__init__()

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL setup
    ##
    ## First initialize `moveit_commander`_ and a `rospy`_ node:
    moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
    rospy.init_node('move_group_python_interface_tutorial',
                    anonymous=True)
    
    ## Instantiate a `RobotCommander`_ object. This object is the outer-level interface to
    ## the robot:
    robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander()
    
    ## Instantiate a `PlanningSceneInterface`_ object.  This object is an interface
    ## to the world surrounding the robot:
    scene = moveit_commander.PlanningSceneInterface()

    ## Instantiate a `MoveGroupCommander`_ object.  This object is an interface
    ## to one group of joints.  In this case the group is the joints in the Panda
    ## arm so we set ``group_name = panda_arm``. If you are using a different robot,
    ## you should change this value to the name of your robot arm planning group.
    ## This interface can be used to plan and execute motions on the Panda:
    group_name = "arm"
    group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(group_name)
    group.set_planning_time(0.1)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    current_planning_time = group.get_planning_time()
    rospy.loginfo({current_planning_time})
    ## We create a `DisplayTrajectory`_ publisher which is used later to publish
    ## trajectories for RViz to visualize:
    display_trajectory_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/move_group/display_planned_path',
                                                   moveit_msgs.msg.DisplayTrajectory,
                                                   queue_size=20)

    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL

    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL basic_info
    ##
    ## Getting Basic Information
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    # We can get the name of the reference frame for this robot:
    planning_frame = group.get_planning_frame()

    # We can also print the name of the end-effector link for this group:
    eef_link = group.get_end_effector_link()

    # We can get a list of all the groups in the robot:
    group_names = robot.get_group_names()

    # Sometimes for debugging it is useful to print the entire state of the
    # robot:
    print "============ Printing robot state"
    print robot.get_current_state()
    print ""
    ## END_SUB_TUTORIAL

    # Misc variables
    self.box_name = ''
    self.robot = robot
    self.scene = scene
    self.group = group
    self.display_trajectory_publisher = display_trajectory_publisher
    self.planning_frame = planning_frame
    self.eef_link = eef_link
    self.group_names = group_names

  def go_to_joint_state(self):
    
    # Copy class variables to local variables to make the web tutorials more clear.
    # In practice, you should use the class variables directly unless you have a good
    # reason not to.
    group = self.group
    ## BEGIN_SUB_TUTORIAL plan_to_joint_state
    ##
    ## Planning to a Joint Goal
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ## The Panda's zero configuration is at a `singularity <https://www.quora.com/Robotics-What-is-meant-by-kinematic-singularity>`_ so the first
    ## thing we want to do is move it to a slightly better configuration.
    # We can get the joint values from the group and adjust some of the values:
    joint_goal = group.get_current_joint_values()

    x = 0
    for i in range(100):
      try:
        joint_goal[0] += 0.01
        # x += 1
        # if x == 10:
        startime = time.time()
        group.go(joint_goal, wait=True)
        endtime = time.time()
          # x = 0
        print(endtime-startime)
        time.sleep(0.1)
      except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return
    # Calling ``stop()`` ensures that there is no residual movement

    group.stop()

what is stopping the programm from running faster? Also when running moveit the cpu usage is 50% and when running the above program it goes up to 75%. so is it maby a hardware constraint?

You're asking about performance and system tuning questions. To help with that you will need to share information about your overall system and how you're launching it. Likely your full system is too complicated to effectively share. To get the best help please try to make a minimum reproducible example of your problem that can then be solved and taken back to your specific application.

this is just a modified version of the example code provided with moveit 1 adjusted for a five axis robot, but it schould work with the standart example, but in my problem its controlling this https://github.com/jesseweisberg/moveo_ros also i have an about 10 year old i7 with 8 cores

They doesn't explain what you're running in your system or what your parameters are. They are critical to understanding performance. Please consider making a simple minimum problem you can explain concisely for people to help you. Otherwise we only have your description which is very open ended and answers would be guessing how to help you.

it is an ubuntu 16.04 system with ros kinetic and moveit 1 it has 16gb of ram(specificly a dell latitude e6530) i am using python 2.7 on the ros side and trying to get moveit to plan fast with a sender that sends at least 10 times a second

You mention your hardware, but what about your software and all their parameters. As I said before a small reproducible example will be best to help you.

Also, you're using very old versions of ROS and Ubuntu both of which are long ago unsupported so help here will likely be harder to come by as well, with people being less familiar and features missing in the older version.

The projekt i am using only supports these old versions. but could you tell me the parameters you need to know to reconstruct the error

Please understand, I have little to no information about what you are running on your system. You need to share enough information about your system to enable someone to help you. The best way to do this is a minimum reproducible example. Often as you refine the problem scope to be something that is easy enough to explain fully you can find the fix yourself.

simplified just a loop that adds 0.1 to the rotation of some joint on some robot in moveit 10 times a second. thats what i am trying to achieve. but moveit is to slow. the ros system just consists of the sender(the loop) and the reciever(moveit)
